# Is there any difference between "MonadIO m" and "MonadBaseControl IO m"?

Tags: haskell, monads, conduit

Function [runTCPClient](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-conduit-1.0.0/docs/Data-Conduit-Network.html#v:runTCPClient) from *network-conduit* has the following signature:

```
runTCPClient :: (MonadIO m, MonadBaseControl IO m)
             => ClientSettings m -> Application m -> m ()
```

`MonadIO m` provides

```
liftIO :: IO a -> m a
```

and `MonadBaseControl IO m` provides

```
liftBase :: IO a -> m a
```

There is no visible difference. Do they provide the same functionality? If yes, why the duplication in the type signature? If not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`liftBase` is part of [`MonadBase`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-base-0.4.1/docs/Control-Monad-Base.html#t:MonadBase) which is a generalization of `MonadIO` for any base monad and, as you said, `MonadBase IO` provides the same functionality as `MonadIO`.

However, [`MonadBaseControl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-0.3.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl) is a bit more complicated beast. In `MonadBaseControl IO m` you have

```
liftBaseWith :: ((forall a. m a -> IO (StM m a)) -> IO a) -> m a
restoreM     :: StM m a -> m a
```

It's easiest to see what the practical uses are by looking at examples. For example, the [`bracket`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:bracket) from `base`has the signature

```
bracket ::  IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> IO c) -> IO c
```

With just `MonadBase IO m` (or `MonadIO m`) you can lift the main `bracket` invocation into `m` but the bracketing actions still need to be in plain old `IO`.

`throw` and `catch` are maybe even better examples:

```
throw :: Exception e => e -> a
catch :: Exception e => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a
```

You can easily thrown an exception from any `MonadIO m` and you can catch exception from `IO a` inside `MonadIO m` but again, both the action being run in `catch` and the exception handler itself need to be `IO a` not `m a`.

Now `MonadBaseControl IO` makes it possible to write `bracket` and `catch` in a way that allows the parameter actions to also be of type `m a` instead of being restricted to the base monad. The generic implementation for the above functions (as well as many others) can be found in the package [`lifted-base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base). For example:

```
catch   :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, Exception e) => m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a
bracket :: MonadBaseControl IO m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> m c
```

**EDIT**: And now that I actually re-read your question properly...

No, I don't see any reason why the signature requires both `MonadIO m` and `MonadBaseControl IO m` since `MonadBaseControl IO m` should imply `MonadBase IO m` which enables the exact same functionality. So maybe it's just a left-over from some older version.

Looking at the source, it's probably just because `runTCPClient` calls `sourceSocket` and `sinkSocket` internally and those require `MonadIO`. I'm guessing that the reason why all the functions in the package don't simply use `MonadBase IO` is that `MonadIO` is more familiar to people and most monad transformers have a instance defined for `MonadIO m => MonadIO (SomeT m)` but users might have to write their own instance for `MonadBase IO`.

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense. What confused me was that [`MonadBaseControl` in _conduit_](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.9.3/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:MonadBaseControl) lacks any definition, probably only the name is imported/re-exported there.