# How to call liftIO from MonadBaseControl IO m?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm writing a function `publish`, which needs to do some `IO`, and also call a function in `MonadBaseControl IO m`.The following works, but I would like to get rid of the constraint for `MonadIO`, since it should be redundant with `MonadBaseControl`

```
publish :: (MonadIO m, MonadBaseControl IO m) => m ()
publish =
  withResource $ \r ->
    liftIO $ someIOAction r
```

[`withResource`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.3/resource-pool-0.2.3.2/Data-Pool.html#v:withResource) is defined in Data.Pool, and has a `MonadBaseControl IO m` constraint.

`someIOAction` has the type `r -> IO ()`

I've read this question, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the second constraint: [Is there any difference between "MonadIO m" and "MonadBaseControl IO m"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931277/is-there-any-difference-between-monadio-m-and-monadbasecontrol-io-m)

If I remove `MonadIO m` then I don't have `liftIO` anymore. How do I execute an IO action from `MonadBaseControl?`

Comment: Isn't `liftBase` all you need instead of `liftIO`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`MonadBase`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-base-0.4.4/docs/Control-Monad-Base.html#t:MonadBase) class which is a superclass of `MonadBaseControl`:

```
class (Applicative b, Applicative m, Monad b, Monad m) =>
      MonadBase (b :: * -> *) (m :: * -> *) | m -> b where
  liftBase :: b α -> m α
```

So you can `liftBase $ someIOAction r`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it was a superclass, I thought it was a separate effort. Thanks!